# Get all photos, videos of Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

In **tumblr.com**, are there any API to collect media data such as photos, videos of an account?
Like Facebook, there are Photo , Album feature which allow user to get photos.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sadly your question is lacking in effort. I would suggest reading this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumblr is blog-based.
So, you can't post a photo or video like Facebook.
Therefore, you **can not** retrieve photos, videos via Tumblr developer site http://www.tumblr.com/developers

I think there is only way to do this job is you can get all posts of a blog, then detect whether there type are photo/video. Then, extract photos/videos from posts.

Comment: You don't need to request all the posts, you request target specific post types via the API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#video-posts

Comment: @mikedidthis : you're right. We dont need to get all posts.It's redundant. Thanks.